# How to save session data in table without getting expired session?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-timeout

I am new for php with codeigniter. I have a issue about php session with codeigniter mvc framework. When I have used table(ci-sessions) to store session data when I can not login in our site due to session expiration.

I have set `var $sess_table_name = 'ci_sessions';` & `var $sess_use_database = TRUE;` in `Session` class.

I have also set `$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;` & `$config['sess_table_name']= 'ci_sessions';` in `config.php.`

Give good solution about it.

Answer (score 0):

In your config, change the line with $config['sess_expiration'] to :
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;

This will ensure the session does not expire or set it as per your requirement.

Thanks

Comment: I have changed the line with $config['sess_expiration'] to : $config['sess_expiration'] = 0;   but I have no solution about it